# Машинный код(секция .text)

Tags: c++, файлы, компиляция, машинный-код

Начал изучать стадии компиляции. Начал смотреть, что находится в объектных файлах через objdump. Но так и не понял, что именно хранится в секции данных .text. То есть когда я хочу посмотреть сам машинный код(просто посмотреть как он выглядит), при выводе в консоль содержимое секции данных '.text' всё равно дизассемблируется и выводится ассемблерный код. И что там вообще находится(в секции .text) 0 и 1? Или что-то другое?

Comment: Там находятся байты, как бы странно это не звучало :) вся информация на компьютере представлена как последовательность единиц и нулей :) там и есть ассемблерные комманды, поэтому вы их там и видите :)

Comment: `objdump -s ./a.out |less` и в нем (т.е. уже в less) `/.text` -- показывеат что вы хотели -- `Contents of section .text:
 0660 31ed4989 d15e4889 e24883e4 f050544c  1.I..^H..H...PTL
 0670 8d057a02 0000488d 0d030200 00488d3d .....`  / Ну, а `objdump -d ./a.out |less` (дизассемблер) вы уже смотрели. Просто сопоставьте